# What do dollar and colon represent in React?

Tags: reactjs, path, react-router-v4

What do colon and dollar given below mean in React?

**Example for colon:**

<Route path={'/movie/:id'} component={Movie} />

**Example for dollar, (its used right before the expression but why):**

<Link to={`/movie/${this.state.movies[index].id}`} key={index} className="movieLink">

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, the concept regarding dollar is clear. 

Appreciate your assistance. :-) 

Having said that from the first example I removed the colon from the url and found that the component doesn't render though the url changes properly. 

Just to add I am using an API here and the content is getting pulled from an external source "themoviedb.org". 

**Does colon has any specific purpose when it comes to external\internal resource?**

Comment: the colon is a param. are you reading the docs? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params

Comment: I was going through docs from **reactjs.org**. Thanks a lot for your assistance as well as the url for reference. It was of utmost help. Appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$ is not of react. But its ES6 feature called template literals more at [Template Literals basic](http://learnveryeasily.blogspot.com/2018/07/template-literals.html)  or [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

In react, you have Route and Link components in react router module.

Route takes two properties: `path and component`. When a path matches the path given to the  component, it will return the component specified

In your Route, you are saying to match any path which is of movie/anyid which means it navigates to the component specified (here Movie) with the given parameter

Link is used to specify which path to go to. Its just a wrapper of `<a>` tag and helps in navigating to the specified path and in your current example, its to /movie/1 (assuming this.state.movies[index].id is 1)

Answer (score 4):

Well its a **JavaScript ES6** feature ,

As you can imagine before ES6 you can do something like :

```
var user = 'xyz' + newuser;
```

ES6:

```
var user = `xyz${newuser}`;
```

Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (``` `` ```) , Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces `(${expression})`.

You can read more about [Template literals on Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 3):

I too have spent ages trying to find out how the colon works. It's pretty frustrating to have to try and reverse engineer the examples rather than having it explained in the API section.

Having said that, there is a hint in the documentation https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route where it says that the path accepts "Any valid URL path or array of paths that path-to-regexp@^1.7.0 understands". If you look at the documentation for path-to-regexp you can see that "Named parameters are defined by prefixing a colon to the parameter name ... By default, the parameter will match until the following path segment"

Then you can look at https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/match which explains how to get hold of a `match` object and how you can extract the parameters from it.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar is an es6 syntax to use variables in strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `:` is, in this case, part of the `path-to-regexp` syntax used by React Router (and Express) for paths; it allows you to specify a parameter. This has two implications.

1. To match multiple urls.

```js
<Route path='/app/:page'>
```

Will match any `/app/` followed by anything.
Note that there are flexible match types here, but they're not typical regex, exactly: https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0

2. The second purpose of this is to make the parameter (whatever comes after `/app/`) available, via React Router's `useParams` hook (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams).

For a good example of the syntax, check out the "Route Parameters" section on this page:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html